# Why @SpringBootApplication makes variables visible under multithreading environment

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, volatile

When I test how volatile works. I write these codes in SpringBootApplication class and forget to delete @SpringBootApplication. as result, the threadA stops running when mainThread set test to true. However, it should be running without volatile added behind test. Why @SpringBootApplication makes the test visible like volatile does?

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class FeignDemoApplication {
    private static boolean test = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Thread-Main :" + test);
        Thread threadA = new Thread(() -> {
            while (!test) {
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " :" + test);
        }, "ThreadA");
        threadA.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        test = true;
        System.out.println("main stop:" + test);
    }
}
```

With @SpringBootApplication the result is

```
Thread-Main :false
main stop:true
ThreadA :true
Process finished with exit code 0
```

without @SpringBootApplication :

```
Thread-Main :false
main stop:true
```

and keeps running

Comment: Although the difference is curious, please note that absence of `volatile` does not guarantee or imply it keeps running, it is the exact opposite: it is the *presence* of `volatile` that guarantees the change will be seen and thus guarantees this will stop. You cannot and should not expect the opposite behaviour always occurs in the absence of `volatile`.

Comment: I am getting similar result when using with or without spring boot. Spring boot version : 2.4.2, Java17.  Share your version of spring boot & java which you are using here.